# Pythonic way of comparing multiple elements in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries in **Python**. Each element of the list has a `type` key with the element's type. Something like this:

```
e1 = {"type": 1, "value": 23.1}
e2 = {"type": 1, "value": 21.1}
e3 = {"type": 2, "value": -10.1}
e4 = {"type": 1, "value": -2.59}
l = [e1, e2, e3, e4]
```

I would like to know if all elements in list `l` are of the same `type`.

I have this:

```
def same_type(l):
    return l[0].type == l[1].type == l[2].type == l[3].type
```

Assuming list are always going to be the same size, is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: not only all answers but I like you question too...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First thing that comes into my head:

```
all(e['type'] == L[0]['type'] for e in L)
```

The length of set of types:

```
len(set(e['type'] for e in L)) == 1
```

is more efficient than `all` with a generator, but not with a list:

```
>>> %timeit all(e['type'] == l[0]['type'] for e in l)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 784 ns per loop

>>> %timeit len(set(e['type'] for e in l)) == 1
1000000 loops, best of 3: 676 ns per loop

>>> %timeit all([e['type'] == l[0]['type'] for e in l])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 602 ns per loop
```

With cached `l[0]['type']`:

```
>>> t1 = l[0]['type']
>>> %timeit all([e['type'] == t1 for e in l])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 447 ns per loop

>>> %timeit all(e['type'] == t1 for e in l)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 655 ns per loop
```

`set` with a list-comp is even slower then with a genexpr:

```
>>> %timeit len(set([gettype(e) for e in l])) == 1
1000000 loops, best of 3: 735 ns per loop
```

I thought of another way that's faster then `set` when there are no possibilities to short-circuit:

```
>>> %timeit [e['type'] for e in l].count(t1) == len(l)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 421 ns per loop
```

Another edit: apparently the most straightforward method is the fastest:

```
In [31]: def same_type(L):
   ....:     t1 = L[0]['type']
   ....:     for e in L:
   ....:         if e['type'] != t1:
   ....:             return False
   ....:     return True
   ....:

In [32]: %timeit same_type(l)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 352 ns per loop
```

**Long input with the same type (no short-circuiting)**

```
In [47]: l = [{'type': 1} for _ in range(1000)]

In [48]: %timeit same_type(l)
10000 loops, best of 3: 37.6 us per loop

In [49]: %timeit  all(e['type'] == l[0]['type'] for e in l)
10000 loops, best of 3: 112 us per loop

In [50]: %timeit all([e['type'] == l[0]['type'] for e in l])
10000 loops, best of 3: 103 us per loop

In [51]: %timeit len(set(e['type'] for e in l)) == 1
10000 loops, best of 3: 63.3 us per loop
```

**Long input with different types (short-circuit right away)**

```
In [40]: l = [{'type': x} for x in range(1000)]

In [43]: %timeit same_type(l)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 337 ns per loop

In [44]: %timeit  all(e['type'] == l[0]['type'] for e in l)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 656 ns per loop

In [45]: %timeit all([e['type'] == l[0]['type'] for e in l])
10000 loops, best of 3: 99.4 us per loop

In [46]: %timeit len(set(e['type'] for e in l)) == 1
10000 loops, best of 3: 68.6 us per loop
```

Comment: I think that's supposed to be `L[0]['type']`?

Comment: Be very careful with your timings here.  `all` with a generator will beat out the list if you get input which is good for short-circuiting.  Also, you haven't tried `set` with a list-comp which may (or may not) do better than `set` with a genexp.

Comment: What is your test input; the timings between the two approaches depend on the input size and distribution of the second type (if present).

Comment: My test input is from the question. I'll try some long lists with and without different types.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `set()` to collect all the types, then test if it is length 1:

```
def same_type(L):
    if not L: return True  # empty list case
    return len(set(d['type'] for d in L)) == 1
```

This has to scan all elements. You could also compare against the *first* element, at which point you only need to test enough to find one that doesn't match:

```
def same_type(L):
    if not L: return True  # empty list case
    t = L[0]['type']
    return all(t == d['type'] for d in L)
```

For *smaller* inputs the `set()` approach is faster, but for *larger* inputs the second form can beat out the `set()` approach if the likelihood of there being a second type in the input is large enough.

Comment: wow... pretty clever. would it be faster than the other two answers (which are basically the same...)

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz: I expect `all()` to be faster.

Comment: If `d` is large and performance really matters, you would want to cache `l[0]['type']`.

Comment: Hi Martijn! why do you use  `l[1:]` ? where as Pavel simply write `in L)` in his `all` expression, he don't use slicing.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Because for the *first* element there is no point in testing if the type is the same.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan:  I suppose it's one less test, but I suspect it loses out by copying most of the list.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski ahaa steven.. very good point I'm a bit surprised!

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: True; switched to using an iterator instead.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Removed the slice altogether now, even using `iter()` only slows things down.

Answer (score 4):

Works for any length of `lst`:

```
def same_type(lst):
    return all(d['type'] == lst[0]['type'] for d in lst[1:])
```

comparing to `len(set(...)) == 1` it is faster, because it stops as soon as a different `type` is found.